# How to make cython function accept float or double array input?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cython, blas

Suppose I have the following (MCVE...) cython function

```
cimport cython

from scipy.linalg.cython_blas cimport dnrm2


cpdef double func(int n, double[:] x):
   cdef int inc = 1
   return dnrm2(&n, &x[0], &inc)
```

Then, I cannot call it on a `np.float32` array `x`.

How could I make `func` accept a `double[:]` or a `float[:]`, and call `dnrm2` or `snrm2` alternatively? The only solution I have currently is to have two functions, which creates a huge quantity of duplicated code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a fused type. Please note that the below doesn't compile on my system because `ddot` and `sdot` apparently require 5 parameters:

```
# cython: infer_types=True
cimport cython

from scipy.linalg.cython_blas cimport ddot, sdot

ctypedef fused anyfloat:
   double
   float

cpdef anyfloat func(int n, anyfloat[:] x):
   cdef int inc = 1
   if anyfloat is double:
      return ddot(&n, &x[0], &inc)
   else:
      return sdot(&n, &x[0], &inc)
```

Comment: yep I got confused, I meant dnrm2 (anyway, it's just a dummy example)
Is the "anyfloat is double" a costly overhead?

Comment: @P.Camilleri I don't really know, but my guess would be no.

Comment: The if statement is evaluated at compile time so no overhead at all (you can inspect the generated C code to confirm). The overhead happens when the function is called from Python and it has to pick which version (it can often directly use the right version from Cython though)